# Console "404 Not Found"?

Tags: jquery, ajax, console

i have a script in jquery and when it is initialized, in console appear "GET http://localhost/0", everything working perfectly but in console i have **4** get request error. I use `jQuery.ajax` for init the script.

Screen

[image]

Sometimes there are fewer

[image]

Comment: can u share some code to give light to your problem ??

Comment: sorry, but the code is too large, has 245kb

Comment: Don't post all the code, just the ajax requests so people can see them

Comment: can u post some code ?

Comment: Is `/0` something you know / use ? Can you post a screenshot of `Netowrk` tab of chrome dev tools where the request is done (and fails)?

Comment: The problem has fixed, thanks for advice.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. Open the page in Google Chrome Developer Tools, and go to the Network tab.
2. Click on XHR to filter the Ajax requests. Load your page.
3. In the filter text field, type http://localhost/0 to find the row when the request has been made.
4. Look at the Initiator column (the 5th for me) to see what script/line triggered the request.

As websky suggested, it might be a bug in Dojo.

Comment: Thank you, but i have already fixed this, the problem was: i had  an audio tag with **src="0"** before change the src with audio file.

Comment: @Firuza Ok. I think many people (me at least) came here because the question has a bounty and was unanswered. If you want people to stop answering your question, it's acceptable for you to answer yourself, or to delete it if you think it's best.

Comment: I know, i give'u a reward for the most sympathetic response, look at all the responses have UP vote from me, but I don't understant why my question is worth 2 down.

Comment: Thanks! I think people wanted to get access to your code so they would be able to spot the problem themselves. I suggest you to use http://jsfiddle.net to share your code, and if it's too large (245kb is), try to isolate the problem first using the good technique described here: http://sscce.org/

Answer (score 2):

It is as if your AJAX request was trying to load some resource from your local machine, and it could not (e.g. a file is not present, or local HTTP server is not serving Web pages for some reason). Try and figure out WHAT is being requested by that AJAX request. No way to be more specific without seeing the code.

Comment: Then maybe at least show the AJAX request part of the code (usually starting with  **$.ajax({** ). There's really no way to figure out without looking at that.

Answer (score 1):

> Problem is that Dojo will create request: GET http://localhost/0

https://bugs.dojotoolkit.org/ticket/17011

Answer (score 1):

This question is not a complete question at all.

If you just want that error to be gone, and your code works perfectly as you say.

Then just create a blank file named "`0`" at the root folder of your site.

Next time your ajax should find that file and stop showing you 404 error. 404 error is shown when you request something from server and server can not resolve the URI mostly because of missing file.

Alternately, We could tweak your ajax code, if you had posted it. I recommend posting it for better answer.

Answer (score 1):

You have to include properly your jquery script.

Here it is how to do it:

http://www.w3schools.com/jquery/jquery_get_started.asp

Second, page you are trying to get with your ajax call is maybe blank or does not exist - check that and you will find where is your problem.

Answer (score 0):

You have to clear browser cache as follows:

Right click **Inspect**, go to **Network** tab.

Find the broken link under **Name** (in red).

Right click, '**clear browser cache**' and refresh Chrome.